# I am not able to trasfer file and folder from one server to another server

Tags: php

Please find the following code. In addition to this I forget to state that I am actually running this script on magento web store but it doesn't matter since I am getting all things okay except file transfer.

```html
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$array1=array();
$array2=array();


echo $destination_dir = dirname(__FILE__);


$remote_file = '/B303501/_Datenblatt.pdf';       
$ftp_server = "*******";
$ftp_user = "************";
$ftp_pass = "******";
$local_file = '/E212002M';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

foreach ($products as $product) {
    array_push($array1,$product->getData("sku"));
    array_push($array2,$product->getData("image"));
}

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
    //echo "Connected as $ftp_user@$ftp_server";
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    if(!@copy('/B303501/_Datenblatt.pdf','/media/catalog/product/demo/'))
 {
     $errors= error_get_last();
     echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
     echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
 } else {
     echo "File copied from remote!";
 }
    $i = 0;
 $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
 foreach ($contents as $cont) {
  if(in_array($cont,$array1)){
            echo $cont. "</br>";
            $buff = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '/'.$cont.'/');
            
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($buff);
            echo "</pre>";
            $tobecopied = 'http://www.example.com/index.html';
            $target = $destination_dir . '/media/catalog/product/demo/';

            foreach($buff as $key){
                if(!@copy('/'.$cont.'/'.$key,'/media/catalog/product/demo/'))
    {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
        echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
    } else {
        echo "File copied from remote!";
    }
            }


    $i++;    
        }
 }
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n";
}
```

I am getting following error while file transfer from one server to another server.

I have both live server and I am also get logged-in successfully but can't figure out what's happening while file transfer.

The following is the error.

```html
/var/www/clients/client348/web979/web
COPY ERROR: 2
copy(/B303501/_Datenblatt.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directoryB303501
```

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Let me know if you need any further information regarding above.

Thanks

Comment: How is it PHP related?

Comment: because i need to transfer file between two live servers using php script so it's php related

Comment: Then, please provide the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [ftp_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) not `copy`. Also make sure that directory hierarchy exists at your destination because either `ftp_get` nor `copy` won't create missing directories for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally sort it out issue. The ftp you I am using is just normal ftp but In order to loggedin into another server you need SFTP credentials except this all above is in working mode.

Thanks for your support